# Параметры функции VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите, есть такая функция которая вызывается в VueJS следующим образом 
событие `myEvent` возвращает результат (`result`) при вызове:

```
<tag @myEvent="myFunction"></tag>
```

метод:

```
myFunction(arg){
    console.log(arguments) //result
}
```

как нибудь можно в `myFunction` передать дополнительные параметры примерно так:

```
<tag @myEvent="myFunction(arg)"></tag>
    myFunction(){
    console.log(arguments) //arg ----- как здесь получить result?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[В inline-обработчиках доступен объект `$event`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%B8-inline-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8). Его можно передать в функцию вместе с дополнительными параметрами:

```
<button @click="method($event, параметр)">Кнопка</button>
...
method(event, parameter) {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(parameter);
}
```

---

Сниппет:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    method(event, parameter) {
      console.log(event.target);
      console.log(parameter);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="method($event, 77)">Кнопка</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, убрал свой костыль типа (result)=>{myFunction(result, param)}